# Vertical then Horizontal motion?

Tags: ios

What if want to put two move actions (first move to the horizontal side of the screen then move to the vertical side) in cocos2d actions?Can i get the position of sprite while moving the sprite?

Answer (score 1):

You can use CCSequence to run actions in sequence

```
id actionMoveRight = [CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:1 position:ccp(50,0)];
id actionMoveUp= [CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:1 position:ccp(0,50)];
id actionSequence = [CCSequence actions:actionMoveRight, actionMoveUp, nil];
[mySprite runAction: actionSequence];
```

If you want to run actions at the same time use `CCSpawn`

Comment: I am using the same code but not get the correct output.After completing the horizontal motion the vertical motion is not there.

Comment: can i get the position of sprite while moving